# Can I do this with a SQL function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Just a general question on functions in MS SQL2012. I've been using SQL for 15 years now and have used most things to quite an advanced level but have never ever used a function.

I'm just wondering if a function can be used for the following....

I have a query that has a large case statement, the query is also grouped on the results of the case statement - this means that every change that I make to the case statement I have to replicate in the Group By clause, this is very time consuming to maintain (particularly as I always forget to update the case statement in the group by clause).

**here's a theoretical example of my query....**

```
Select
Field1,
Field2,
Field3,
Field4,
Case
when Field2 like ('%abc%') then 'Category1'
when Field2 like ('%def%') then 'Category2'
/*plus around 20 more 'when' lines*/
else 'CategoryX' end as 'Category'

From table 
Group by
Case
when Field2 like ('%abc%') then 'Category1'
when Field2 like ('%def%') then 'Category2'
/*plus around 20 more 'when' lines*/
else 'CategoryX' end
```

I know I could sub-query this and then group by subQuery.Category but, as I've never used functions before, I just wan't to know if I can create a `Category` function that takes in `Field2`, runs the case statement and outputs the result with the rest of the data in the table?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Yes, you can do exactly that

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff  - haha, yes, point taken!

Comment: @mcr - great, I'll post up my results to complete the question.

Comment: If you have that many elements in your case expression perhaps there is another way to deal with this? Maybe a mapping table for the Category values? Since you say you have never used a function why do you need one now? Be warned that scalar functions can have horrible performance.

Comment: ...I should've also added that the case statement is common across a few different queries - so a function would centralise it.

Comment: @SeanLange - good idea but I'm not sure how I'd go about implementing this as the data comes from the description field of purchase ledger invoices and I need to find parts of a string within the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create inline table function to hide complex logic:

```
    create function dbo.udfGetR 
    (
     --param here
    )
    returns table 
    as return 

   Select
          Field1,
          Field2,
          Field3,
          Field4,
          Case
                when Field2 like ('%abc%') then 'Category1'
                when Field2 like ('%def%') then 'Category2'
                /*plus around 20 more 'when' lines*/
                else 'CategoryX' end as 'Category'

          From table 
          Group by
          Case
          when Field2 like ('%abc%') then 'Category1'
          when Field2 like ('%def%') then 'Category2'
          /*plus around 20 more 'when' lines*/
          else 'CategoryX' end
```

call it

```
         select * from dbo.udfGetR(--param)
```

Comment: I've created the function as above and it works - how do I include it in the original query? do I need to create a key column in the function and then join it like this - Left join dbo.udfGetR uGR on uGR.TransNo = OriginalQuery.TransNo

Comment: ...Solved it with parameters and Cross Apply! - execution time remains the same, so all good!

Answer (score 3):

Better than a user-defined function (in my opinion) is a computed column:

```
alter table
    add category as (Case when Field2 like ('%abc%') then 'Category1'
                          when Field2 like ('%def%') then 'Category2'
                          /*plus around 20 more 'when' lines*/
                          else 'CategoryX'
                     end);
```

Why do I like this better than a function?

- It ties the definition to the specific table and `field2` column.
- There is some overhead on calling a user-defined function, so a computed column is faster.
- You have the opportunity to create an index on `category`.
- All users of the table will see `category` column and it will be populated correctly.

Modifying the column requires dropping and re-adding it.

One downside is that users need the right permissions to add the column.  And dropping and re-adding the column could have an effect on code that uses SCHEMABINDING.  (Why doesn't SQL Server allow modification of computed columns?)

Note that both this solution and a function do have a weakness:  The logic is not apparent in the query, so the same query run at different times can produce different results.

Comment: Good solution but this wouldn't be appropriate in this case as the table is part of a proprietary accounting database

Answer (score 1):

Two other obvious solutions:

Use a CTE:

```
WITH cte As
(
    SELECT
        ...
        CASE
            WHEN Field2 like '%abc%' THEN 'Category1'
            ...
            ELSE 'CategoryX' 
        END As 'Category'
    FROM 
        table 
)
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY
    Category
;
```

Use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT
    ...
    C.Category
FROM 
    table As T
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN T.Field2 Like '%abc%' THEN 'Category1'
                ...
                ELSE 'CategoryX'
            END
    ) As C (Category)
GROUP BY
    C.Category
;
```